# Linkedin: Registering Application for both Web and Mobile

Tags: api, linkedin-api

My project deals with both Web app and Mobile app. So before we can use Linkedin API's into our project we need to register our app with Linkedin according to this [Quick Start](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/quick-start-guide). But for my situation where i use Linkedin API's for both web and mobile, Do i need to register two application with Linkedin. Or is there any other way to register a single application and use the same for both web and mobile?

In the registration page i don't see any distinction for Web and Mobile, unlike facebook where a single application registered can be used for both web and mobile app.

If anyone could point me to appropriate docs or pointers, it would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When a user authorizes your LinkedIn Application, their authorization is tied to that particular API key - if you were to use multiple keys in a single user realm, the user would in theory have to authorize both of them.

In short, I don't see any advantage to using multiple keys if your users are going to be exposed to both web and mobile.

Comment: Ya you are right. But how do i deal with it. Its important we have both the apps. Aren't there any apps out similar to our case. I think there must be. If so how are they doing it?

Comment: Why would you want to use two keys, one for each - what are the advantages?

Comment: I am not sure of the advantages but the disadvantage is  - when we provide the redirect url in the application settings it works fine for the web but for mobile it doesn't. In mobile it has to redirect to the application. if we use a single application in mobile it redirects to the web url after linkedin authorization, which becomes difficult to come back to mobile application. I am new to Linkedin API so my knwoledge is very less in this. May be experts like you can guide me. 

Thanks